# Redmine: create issues via GET request

Tags: jira, redmine, redmine-plugins

In JIRA it is possible to create new issues through a simple GET request: http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Creating+Issues+via+direct+HTML+links.

A simple example of such a link:

"http://jira.atlassian.com/secure/CreateIssueDetails!init.jspa?pid=10420&issuetype=3&summary=say+hello+world"

This would create a new issue in project with PID=1042 with summary "Say Hello world".

Is there Redmine plugin/api which allows for such a use case? The REST API is inconvenient for my use since I would like to allow users to create new issues (with pre filled data) through a link sent in email and I don't want to use JavaScript for the job (to send the REST json/xml data).

EDIT:
From what I see (http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/RedmineReceivingEmails) Redmine provides an email API for submitting issues, this would be a parital solution. I would be able to add a "mailto:" link which would pre fill the content of the message.
This solution requires additional emails so still I would prefer to have a post link solution.

Comment: the w3c recommends that GET requests are 'safe'; ie, that they do not modify anything on the server. Redmine will have been designed with this in mind -- you will only be able to create issues by POSTing to /issues with vanilla Redmine.

Comment: This plugin is safe as it does not produce any side effect. It simply opens up a form for reporting an issue and pre-fills it with data provided in the query parameters. The 'Save' button still needs to be clicked to create the report.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have implemented a basic plugin which fulfills my needs. You can find it at:
http://code.google.com/p/redmine-post-link-plugin/

Comment: Not compatible with Redmine 1.3

Comment: Though if you look at the HTML source, the form element name attribute can be used as query string keys for the same functionality.

Answer (score 0):

You could also have a server-side script that actually sends the e-mail. There's no post link solution as far as I know.

Comment: The issue must be registered manually by the user. I don't want this to be done automatically.

Comment: I meant that you could create a page with a form, and when submitting the form, an e-mail is sent out (from the server).

Comment: In stead of reimplementing the "New Issue" form I would prefer to write a Redmine plugin (at least now - this might change after checking Redmine API)

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at the Redmine API for updating and creating issues.

http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/Rest_Issues

Answer (score 0):

In Redmine2 there is [oficial API for it](http://www.redmine.org/issues/9076).